# Выделить в строке слова msg или oh

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно составить регулярное выражение которое выделит в строке слова msg или oh (любой регистр), но только такие, после которых идут пара фигурных скобок с любым содержание внутри {} а после всего этого стоит ;

например такая строка:

```
mSg
{   sda\r\n
sadsa\r\n
da\r\n};
//dfgdg
oh{fsdf}; jj
msg {ddd
msg

msg {     sda\r\n
sadsa\r\n
da\r\n};
//dfgdfg
```

Пробовал так:

```
(msg|oh)(?=(\s*{(\s|.)*}\s*;))
```

выходит следующее:

```
mSg              //выделилось (как и должно)
{   sda\r\n
sadsa\r\n
da\r\n};
//dfgdg
oh{fsdf}; jj         //выделилось (как и должно)
msg {ddd        //но ещё выделилось это (а не должно, ведь нет закрывающей скобки)
msg                     //не выделилось (как и должно)

msg {     sda\r\n     //выделилось (как и должно)
sadsa\r\n
da\r\n};
//dfgdfg
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка в том, что опережающее условие ***(?=...)*** - нельзя делать проверку на неопределенную длину. Т.е: **+** или *****

Как-то так:

```
"/(oh|msg)\s*(?=\{)(?:\{[^\{]*?\})/gis"
```

Выделит из вашего примера все ***msg*** и ***oh***, после которых идет "**{**" и присутствует закрывающая фигурная скобка

Флаги:
**g** - глобальный поиск
**i** - регистро-независимый
**s** - cчитать текст одной строкой

Живой пример:  [ссылка](http://regex101.com/r/aC8uF1)

Comment: @ололо, Я в начале невнимательно прочел Ваш вопрос. Подправил свой ответ